# AJAX success html dialog, won't close on button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

So I've made an AJAX request, it submits fine and returns the HTML on success as expected - but in the HTML that is returned to the target div element, it has a button. I've added jQuery to this, that when it's clicked, it is to hide the HTML from the AJAX success.

In short: I want the close button to close the div, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('#user_report__dd #make_report').click(function(){
        var interaction_type = $(this).data('interaction_type');
        var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                interaction_type: interaction_type,
                user_id: user_id,
            },
            success:function(html){
                // $('.ajax_call').html(html);
                $('.ajax_call').html(html);
                // stop body from scrolling
            }
        });
    });
```

```
if(isset($_POST['interaction_type']) && $_POST['interaction_type'] == 'report_user'){
    global $report;
    $report->Form($_POST['user_id'], 'user');
    // This returns the HTML
}
```

And then in my main jQuery file

```
$('.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.pulled_in_html');
    });
```

Comment: To point you in the right direction, just like @matt did, use the "on" for your event listener. When you use the `click` event listener you attach it to an existing element, so when you javascript loads, you're trying to attach the event listener to an element that doesn't yet exist, while his `$('body').on('click', '.close', ...)` will attach the event listener to the existing body element and listen for all clicks within the body element and trigger for any child elements with the class "close".

Comment: Understood. So how would you tackle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the element doesn't exist in the DOM when your click event handler is created, it doesn't find the element. Instead you can delegate the event from `body` like below:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).parents('.pulled_in_html');
});
```

> Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to
>   specific nodes; instead, the event listener is added to one parent.
>   That event listener analyzes bubbled events to find a match on child
>   elements.

You can read more about event delegation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Your code doesn't seem to be making any attempt at hiding anything and I don't know if you left this out on purpose or not, but to hide the element, you can chain the `hide()` method onto this line:

```
    $(this).parents('.pulled_in_html').hide();
```

Comment: It definitely shouldn't, what other events do you have?

Comment: I've added it all in a JSFiddle. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/9h21rxtu/